# GUI Scripts (Power Automate) not working in minimized Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

**Problems statement :** GUI Windows Automation scripts not running when minimizing the Remote Desktop Connection. Windows scripts done in power automate. Scripts perfectly working when we open the Remote Desktop.

**What i have tried** Tried this below article steps. https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/in-minimized-window.html

RegKey changes Set/create Dword to 2 for following path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
```

But I couldnt see Terminal server Client for HKEY_CURRENT_USER

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
```

I Need to run my scripts in minimized Remote Desktop.